# Does it matter how many Nth authors there are on a literature review?

Tags: publications, authorship

I am a student hoping to kick start my research career (biochemistry). I hope to start a PhD in the coming months and in the meantime have drafted a review which I hope to submit in the next few weeks.

I was wondering if it is important how many second/third/etc authors there are on the paper? At the moment I would have had 3 other people contribute/proof-read my review (including our PI), and potentially a 4th. When it comes to job hunting later on, or becoming a reputable researcher, would they check to see how many other authors worked on this review, or would it only matter that I am first author and the quality of the paper itself? In other words, is the lower the number of authors on a review the better, or does it not matter?

Comment: It might matter in some fields, and I'm not familiar with yours. However, proofreading isn't enough to earn authorship. Make sure people contribute _intellectual content_  if you want to make them authors.

Comment: It's unlikely a review paper at your career stage counts for much at all besides your own learning. Grad schools want students who will excel in research, and writing a review doesn't say much about that.

Answer (score 2):

Whether a review has one, two or more authors does not really matter in biochemistry, but being first author is useful, and so is a good quality paper that gets cited. It will be very helpful for your career to build a network and show your skills, and a good way to do so is to collaborate on a review.

Buffy's comment is also correct: authors should contribute intellectually to a paper to earn authorship.

I don't mean to discourage you, but unless you are an exceptionally talented student and scientific writer, you probably *need* help from someone who has experience writing and publishing reviews to get your work accepted.

Most people would agree that there is a difference between a review written by 1-5 authors and one by 20 authors (if those exist - I do not remember reading one). And of course there are always the rare exceptions of readers who value single author papers more (you did everything yourself), or who may prefer multiple-author papers (you can collaborate).